# How to assign a command to a "microsoft-edge" pseudo protocol on Windows 10 without using Microsoft Store

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, microsoft-edge

I am trying to get [EdgeDeflector](https://github.com/da2x/EdgeDeflector) to work to stop Windows from randomly opening Edge for links that come with system dialogs. It's enough that those links are usually useless and opened by accident, having to also wait for another browser to start is really annoying.

Unfortunately, the program no longer works out of the box. One needs to change the setting in "Default apps by protocol" to open `microsoft-edge` links in the EdgeDeflector. But that option is not there:

[image]

I am assuming there must be an associated registry entry? Where can I change this to an arbitrary program?

Comment: In theory it should be HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\microsoft-edge\shell\open\command but at least when testing it myself anything I put there was just ignored. It could very well be that Microsoft hard coded it to always link to Edge (after all they made this protocol literally to force Edge for certain scenarios)

Comment: Realistically if what I am reading, from the developer of the tool, there is no way to get this working on Windows 10 22H2 or Windows 11 22H2+.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EdgeDeflector is now defunct, but it has a replacement :
[MSEdgeRedirect](https://github.com/rcmaehl/MSEdgeRedirect).

MSEdgeRedirect is still in beta and is currently at version 0.7.5.0,
but it's still under development, with the last update dating from
last month. The developer also answers issue-reports, in case you
encounter a problem while using this beta version.

For a write-up about MSEdgeRedirect see the article
[MSEdgeRedirect for Windows 10 and Windows 11 can now redirect Bing searches to Google](https://mspoweruser.com/msedgeredirect-can-now-redirect-bing-searches-to-google/).